# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined when $http.get JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

briefing: 
When reading a JSON file from angularJS, it loads but it pass some time until data is available or something strange similar.

The JSON is:

```
{
  "number": 1,
  "persons":[
    {
      "gender": "Male",
      "name": "Paul",
    }
  ]
}
```

The angular code is:

```
app.controller('myapp', function($scope,$http){
    var folder = 'DB/';
    $http.get(folder+'database.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.DataBase= data;
    });

    console.log($scope);

    $scope.getname= function(){
        return $scope.DataBase.persons[0].name;
    }
```

The html is:

```
<body> 
    <div class="d_name" ng-controller="myapp">
        {{getname()}}
    </div>
</body>
```

What I don't understand is why the console.log($scope) just after getting the JSON shows that there is the object DataBase 
but the function getname() gives two errors before it works, is like if for a while the scope wasn't update and the getname function isn't finding the object, but then why the log is showing it?

The console:

```
ChildScope {$$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: null, $$listeners: Object…}
$$ChildScope: null
$$childHead: null
$$childTail: null
$$listenerCount: Object
$$listeners: Object
$$nextSibling: ChildScope
$$prevSibling: null
$$watchers: Array[3]
$$watchersCount: 3
$id: 4
$parent: ChildScope
DataBase: Object
persons: Array[1]
number: 1
__proto__: Object
getgen: ()
getimg: ()
getname: ()
__proto__: ChildScope

ionic.bundle.js:21157 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'persons' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.getname (http://localhost:63342/test/www/js/controllers/c_menu.js:27:35)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/test/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21972:15), <anonymous>:4:209)
    at Object.expressionInputWatch [as get] (http://localhost:63342/test/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22954:31)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:63342/test/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24502:40)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:63342/test/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24778:24)
    at done (http://localhost:63342/test/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19191:47)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:63342/test/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19363:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://localhost:63342/test/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19304:9)

ionic.bundle.js:21157 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'persons' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.getname (http://localhost:63342/test/www/js/controllers/c_menu.js:27:35)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/test/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21972:15), <anonymous>:4:209)
    at Object.expressionInputWatch [as get] (http://localhost:63342/test/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22954:31)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:63342/test/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24502:40)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:63342/test/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24778:24)
    at done (http://localhost:63342/test/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19191:47)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:63342/test/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19363:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://localhost:63342/test/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19304:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because $ http works asynchronously. Try this:

**The controller:**

```
app.controller('myapp', function($scope,$http){
    var folder = 'DB/';
    $http.get(folder+'database.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.DataBase = data;
        $scope.namePerson = $scope.DataBase.persons[0].name;
    });
});
```

**The html is:**

```
<body> 
    <div class="d_name" ng-controller="myapp">
        {{namePerson}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Emir, you where very fast... But why the console just after shows the object correctly? and This code is a simplification, each person has 5 fields and there are giong to be more than 50 persons, also there are other fields in the JSON root

Comment: Your problem is not in $scope be in  $scope.DataBase. This is indefined

Comment: but $scope.DataBase appears with all the fields in the log

Comment: Try this test: console.log($scope.DataBase) after look the console

Comment: it returns an empty object, so Quentin was right marking it as duplicated, is an asynchronous problem

Comment: Exactly, this returning empty and you are accessing $ scope.DataBase.persons [0] .name ; something null or empty. When you wheel is actually running " ".persons [ 0] .name ; or undefined.persons [ 0] .name ;